# Call gRPC service (Go-micro) from Go client through Traefik

Tags: docker, traefik, go-micro

I'm using **Go-micro, Docker, Traefik** to deploy my service. I deployed go-micro service and registered with **Traefik**. [This is my sum(grpc service) status in Traefik dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHqNO.png). When i curl it in Terminal, I got [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWLWf.png), I thought it's grpc message in binary. But when I used this code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    proto "gomicro-demo/client/service"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/metadata"
    "log"
)

func main() {


    con, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:8080", grpc.WithInsecure())

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Connection error: ", err)
    }

    md := metadata.New(map[string]string{"Host": "sum.traefik"})
    ctx := metadata.NewOutgoingContext(context.Background(), md)

    service := proto.NewSumClient(con)
    res, err2 := service.GetSum(ctx, &proto.Request{})

    if err2 == nil {
        fmt.Println(res)
    } else {
        log.Fatal("Call error:", err2)
    }

}
```

i got this error **rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = Not Found: HTTP status code 404; transport: received the unexpected content-type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"**. I can't know how this error happen, because of address or grpc metadata (Host header). Please help me with this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can export tcp like it. please using trefik2,
`HostSNI` must be seted

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - redis
  routes:
  - match: HostSNI(`*`)
    services:
    - name: redis
      port: 6379
```